# How can resize boxes, if I remove 2 of them?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can resize boxes, if I remove 2 of them?
For example, I have 6 boxes, and I remove 2 of them, the other 4 should change their width.
How can I do this, any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Is it react related question? Tag surely suggest that but I don't know really. Are those boxes react components? Despite that - I would suggest you to go with flexbox

Comment: @Marcus, the question will be closed without answers since you have not shared what you have tried, SO is not Search engine, you have to share what you have tried.

Comment: You would do this with JavaScript, CSS and HTML. How far did you get, where did you get stuck? Where’s your “*[mcve]*” code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex:

```css
.box{
  background-color:gray;
  height:150px;
  margin:25px;
  flex:1 1 0;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid, flexbox or even set width manually. Everything is possible in React world. Well, for the last one you have to be quite tricky!

**Example of each approach**

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

const getItems = () => Promise.resolve(Array(6).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({id: index})))

const random = () => Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1.4))

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const thirdContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const [thirdContainerSize, setThirdContainerSize] =   useState({
  width: 0,
  height: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;
    let handle = null;
    
    getItems()
      .then(items => {
        if(!isUnmounted) {
          setItems(items);
        }
      })
     
    const loop = () => {
      getItems()
      .then(items => {
        if(!isUnmounted) {
          let filtered = items.slice(0, 4);
          
          if(random()) {
            filtered = items.slice(0, 6);
          }
          
          setItems(filtered);
        }
      })
    
      handle = setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
    
    handle = setTimeout(loop, 1000);
     
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handle);
      isUnmounted = true;
    }
  
  }, [])
  
  const computeFlex = () => {
    const flexBasis = items.length === 6 ? 25 : 33;
  
    return {
      flex: `1 1 ${flexBasis}%`
    }
  }
  
  const computeGrid = () => {
    const numberOfcolumns = items.length === 6 ? 3 : 2;
  
    return {
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numberOfcolumns}, auto)`
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(thirdContainerRef && thirdContainerRef.current) {
      const element = thirdContainerRef.current;
    
      setThirdContainerSize(element.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, [thirdContainerRef])
    
  const computeSize = () => {
    
    if(!thirdContainerSize.width) {
      return {}
    }
    
    const containerWidth = thirdContainerSize.width;
    const containerHeight = thirdContainerSize.height;
    const margin = 5 * 2;
    
    const width = items.length === 6 ? (containerWidth / 3) - margin : (containerWidth / 2) - margin;
  
    const height = containerHeight / 2 - margin;
  
    return {
      width: `${width}px`,
      height: `${height}px`,
      float: `left`
    }

  }

return <div>
Flexbox
  <div className="container">
  {items.map(pr => <div key={pr.id} style={computeFlex()} className="item"></div>)}
  </div>
  Grid
  <div style={computeGrid()} className="second-container">
  {items.map(pr => <div key={pr.id} className="item"></div>)}
  </div>
  Width
   <div ref={thirdContainerRef} className="third-container">
    {items.map(pr => <div style={computeSize()} key={pr.id} className="item"></div>)}
  </div>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.second-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
}

.third-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```